Dash Reloading main.py on button click undesirable
My worry here is performance and unnecessary reloading of main script in Dash.
Here is my script. Please keep in mind that my "fake_utils" modules reads files and slow to load. Hence we want to load it once and for all.
main.py
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

from fake_utils import foo
from uuid import uuid4
import diskcache
from dash import Dash, html, DiskcacheManager, Input, Output

launch_uid = uuid4()
cache = diskcache.Cache("./cache")

# Background callbacks require a cache manager
background_callback_manager = DiskcacheManager(
    cache, cache_by=[lambda: launch_uid], expire=60,
)

app = Dash(__name__,
           background_callback_manager=background_callback_manager,
           external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
# I use a background manager because I want to update my progress bar at the same time as running my loop in my main callback (run_process())


app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button('Run Process', id='run-button'),
    dbc.Progress(id="progress-component", value=0, max=10),
    html.Div(id='output')
])

@app.callback(
    Output('output', 'children'),
    Input('run-button', 'n_clicks'),
    background=True,
    progress=[
        Output("progress-component", "value"),
        Output("progress-component", "label"),
    ],
)
def run_process(set_progress, n_clicks):
    if n_clicks is None:
        return html.Div()
    results = []
    for i in range(10):
        # Simulating a process step
        res = foo()
        results.append(res)
        set_progress((i+1, f'{i+1}'))

    #Then do stuff with results

    return 'Done'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=100)

fake_utils.py
import time

print('Importing slow utils')

def foo():
    time.sleep(1)
    return 0

The problem here is that every time i click on the 'Run Process' Button the while main scripts get reloaded (especially fake_utils that takes 3min+)
How can I prevent this behaviour?
You can see 'Importing slow utils' printed multiple times on the console. We can to minimize this.
Thanks in advance.
PS: A solution could be not using the background manager at it seems to be source of the problem, it creates some other processes i think. But would still like to be able to update my progress bar as i go along my loop. This is the documentation of the progress bar in dash

Importing slow utils prints only once for me.
